# C#/XNA How do I get my classes to "speak" to each other?

Tags: c#, class, xna

I'm attempting to build a clone of the first level of Super Mario Bros., but i'm having some trouble getting my classes to "speak" to each other. As of now, I have two Controller classes (keyboard, gamepad) and two animated sprite classes (RunMarioSprite, DeadMarioSprite). What I want to do is switch between these two sprites displaying on the screen based on the keyboard/gamepad input from the user. If key F is pressed, Mario should be displayed running right. If Key D is pressed Mario should move up and down.

What's the proper way of changing which Animated Sprite Class is drawing on the screen through my Controller Classes?

**Keyboard Class**

```
public class KeyboardController : IController
{
    KeyboardState keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
    private IAnimatedSprite marioSprite;
    Texture2D texture;

    public void Update()
    {
        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Q))
        {
            // QUIT GAME    
        }
        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.F))
        {
            // MARIO RUN RIGHT             
        }
        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            // DEAD MARIO UP DOWN

        }
    }
}
```

**Example of an animated sprite class**

```
public class RunMarioSprite : IAnimatedSprite
{
    public Texture2D Texture { get; set; }
    private int currentFrame = 0;
    private int totalFrames = 4;
    public int frameShift = 30;

    public RunMarioSprite(Texture2D texture)
    {
        currentFrame = 0;
        this.Texture = texture;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        currentFrame++;
        if (currentFrame == totalFrames)
            currentFrame = 0;
    }

    public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {

        Rectangle sourceRectangle2 = new Rectangle((240 +(currentFrame*frameShift)), 0, 30, 30);
        Rectangle destinationRectangle2 = new Rectangle(100, 100, 30, 30);

        spriteBatch.Begin();
        spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, destinationRectangle2, sourceRectangle2, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.End();
    }
}


    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();


        // TODO: Add your update logic here
      foreach (IController Controller in ControllerList)
        {
           Controller.Update();
        }

        marioSprite.Update();
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        marioSprite.Draw(this.spriteBatch);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

**Main (Update and Draw)**

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
            this.Exit();


        // TODO: Add your update logic here
      foreach (IController Controller in ControllerList)
        {
           Controller.Update();
        }

        marioSprite.Update();
        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This is called when the game should draw itself.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        marioSprite.Draw(this.spriteBatch);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
```

I apologize if the question is poorly formatted. Thanks for the help!

Comment: What's your problem? How to draw Mario running left or right depending on the input you get?

Comment: @pinckerman I want my keyboard classes to choose the appropriate animated sprite class depending on the input of the user. That is,

if the user hits the 'F' key, I want my RunMarioSprite class to perform its drawing. If the user were to hit the 'D' key I want my DeadMarioSprite to perform its drawing. The actual drawing methods are functioning properly. Just need my KeyboardController class to 'control' everything, but I'm unsure of how to reference the specific classes within that original class. Thanks!

Comment: If the difference between RunMarioSprite and DeadMarioSprite is only the texture to draw you need to change only that, but if they have different behaviours you have to change the instance of marioSprite. In this way your game will draw the correct instance.

Comment: Note: In Main(Update/Draw) marioSprite is of type IAnimatedSprite (the interface for all animated sprite classes). ***Content is loaded as follows: 'spriteSheet = Content.Load<Texture2D>("MarioSpriteSheet");
            marioSprite = new DeadMarioSprite(spriteSheet);'***

Comment: @pinckerman I guess that's my original question. How can I change the instance of marioSprite from my KeyboardController Class?

Comment: You don't have to change the instance in KeyboardController, but in the class that handle the whole game. Don't you have a sprite manager or something like this where you've instanced the classes above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle your `KeyboardController` in your sprite manager class, which have the purpose to draw the whole level you have on screen. Probably you don't need a `KeyboardController`, but only `KeyboardState`:

```
KeyboardController keyboardController = new KeyboardController();

public void Update()
{
   // you should implement a method like this
   KeyboardState keyboard = keyboardController.GetKeyboardState();

   if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.F))
   {
      //change marioSprite instance         
   }
   if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
   {
      //change marioSprite instance
   }
 }
```

Comment: I want to implement a KeyboardController because I also need functionality for a GamepadController. I don't want the code to be located within Update.

Comment: You can create an instance to KeyboardController and a public method that will give you the current pressed key, so the class that has its instance will know what input your game is receiving, or pass the KeyboardState.

Comment: I've edited my answer. The point is that you can't modify your marioSprite form KeyboardController, you have to exploit KeyboardController in your "main" class, I don't know how your named it.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're asking for is a way to know which sprite to draw in your Main.Draw() method based on the keyboard input in another class, you could try something like this:

```
public class Main
{
    public static bool DrawAliveMario;
    RunMarioSprite runmariosprite;
    DeadMarioSprite deadmariosprite;

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        //...

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        if (DrawAliveMario) runmariosprite.Draw(this.spriteBatch);
        else deadmariosprite.Draw(this.spriteBatch);

        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

}
```

And then you could have in your controller classes:

```
public class KeyboardController : IController
{
    KeyboardState keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();

    public void Update()
    {
        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Q))
        {
            // QUIT GAME    
        }
        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.F))
        {
            Main.DrawAliveMario = true;           
        }
        if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.D))
        {
            Main.DrawAliveMario = false;

        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Of course DrawAliveMario is bool, you're missing the type in the declaration.